# The "reset of the scale" flips and destroys my normals

Tags: modeling, normals

I had this mesh with these Normals:

[image]

The column had a "wrong" scale

[image]

and I wanted to set it to 1 1 1. 
Then I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>scale</kbd>.

The result was that:

[image]

The normals are upeset and destroyed (if I flip all with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> the final result isn't good . . .  the normals, although flipped in the right direction, don't come back to the origin.

[image]

My question is: **is there a way to set the scale (1 1 1), avoiding the total distorsion of the normals?** **Or maybe, am I making any mistakes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work to duplicate your object, before applying scale, and use a [Data Transfer Modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/modify/data_transfer.html) to transfer the custom normals from the duplicate object to the corrected object:

[image]

Hopefully that does the trick.